# How can I get the window associated with a SDL_Renderer?

Tags: sdl2

As the title says, is there a member or function to get this?

For example `renderer->window`? Or `renderer.window`? Or so?

Answer (score 3):

As of SDL 2.0.22 there is a function to do this, `SDL_RenderGetWindow`:

```
/**
 * Get the window associated with a renderer.
 *
 * \param renderer the renderer to query
 * \returns the window on success or NULL on failure; call SDL_GetError() for more information.
 *
 * \since This function is available since SDL 2.0.22.
 */
extern DECLSPEC SDL_Window * SDLCALL SDL_RenderGetWindow(SDL_Renderer *renderer);
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Not easily.

You can get the [renderer from the window](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetRenderer), but it doesn't seem like you can go the other way around. This is interesting since if you examine the (internal) definition of the `SDL_Renderer` structure in `SDL_sysrender.h` you can see that it does contain an `SDL_Window *` member referring to the window (named `window`) several bytes in (after a bunch of function pointers).

However, the definition of `SDL_Renderer` is not provided to you in the public headers, so you can't read this member and there does not appear to be an API for exposing it to you.

If you were *particularly* desperate you could copy-paste the definition from the source code to your own source code, cast the `SDL_Renderer *` you have to it, and read the window that way... but that's probably a bad idea as it's quite brittle.

A more practical solution is likely to use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` to maintain your own association between SDL renderers and the window you use to create the renderer.

Comment: Yeah, thanks so much Josh. Not that desperate, so I'll follow your last advice!